# Broken highlighting for digest title with quotes

Tags: bug, design, localization, community-digests

There is a text highlighting issue in the digest letter preview when title contains quotes. For instance:

- [Stack Overflow in Russian Meta](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/digest/preview)

> [image: ruSO Meta Digest preview]

- [Russian Language Stack Exchange](https://rus.stackexchange.com/digest/preview)

> [image: rusSE Digest preview]

For some reason the final quote is outside the span block:

> [image: Span block]

The string used for translation: https://ru.traducir.win/strings/13233